# Adding Motion UI to Joints WP

Tags: wordpress, gulp, zurb-foundation-5, gulp-sass

I installed Foundations Motion UI in the Joints WP theme folder using:

```
npm install motion-ui --save
```

I added the following to the *styles.scss* file:

```
@import "../../node_modules/motion-ui/motion-ui";
@include motion-ui-transitions;
@include motion-ui-animations;
```

If I open *styles.css* I see the pre-made css declarations. And gulp watch runs without any errors.

[In the docs for Motion UI](https://github.com/zurb/motion-ui/blob/master/docs/installation.md) it states:

> To import the Sass files into a project, add the load path
>   `[modules_folder]/motion-ui/src` to your Sass configuration...

I honestly don't know what that means.

I added some of the classed to my code, but haven't gotten any animations or transitions...
What am I missing?